# Noise texture shading

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to add a noise texture to one of my objects, to give it some realism.

In **IMG 01** there's a green shape with some noise texture which has been added within  Photoshop.

In **IMG 02** I added the noise texture, but my colour goes missing. I tried adding different nodes but to no avail.

*What node do I need to add in order for the noise texture and colour to be visible?*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ColorRamp node which maps greyscale values to colored values.

[image: color ramping]

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom image, your Scale value is *very* high -- with the scale that high, and using the "Color" output of the noise texture, the colors aren't going to be distinguishable. Think about looking at a sandy beach from a distance; you can't make out the individual grains of sand.

To make the noise more visible, try turning down the scale (I bet 300 would work well) and using the Fac output (black-and-white) instead of Color.

Comment: Hi Reece.

I'm taking everything into consideration, but regarding the Fac output, if it's black and white, then it's not what I'm trying to achieve. Because almost every object in the real world has some colour applied to it.

Comment: @blenderbreath As covector pointed out above, you can pipe the Fac output through a ColorRamp; that way you can choose colors on the Ramp that have a higher contrast between them than randomly selected colors do.